# JSON output images

Tags: php, json

Fair warning, I'm new to JSON and trying to get the output of a JSON file to properly display in PHP.

The JSON file I have contains:

```
{
"C1": [
    "<img src=\"available.png\">",
    "<img src=\"available.png\">",
    "<img src=\"available.png\">",
    "<img src=\"available.png\">"
],
"C10": [
    "<img src=\"available.png\">",
    "<img src=\"available.png\">",
    "<img src=\"available.png\">",
    "<img src=\"available.png\">"
],
"C11": [
    "<img src=\"available.png\">",
    "<img src=\"available.png\">",
    "<img src=\"available.png\">",
    "<img src=\"available.png\">"
],
"C12": [
    "<img src=\"available.png\">",
    "<img src=\"available.png\">",
    "<img src=\"available.png\">",
    "<img src=\"available.png\">"
]
}
```

This file has a lot more entries of C1, C10, W1, W20, W13 etc and they are generated randomly.

I'm able to get the output of the file in php with:

```
$getJSON            = file_get_contents('file.json');
$json               = json_decode($getJSON, true);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';
```

But I want the output to be in the html form of:

```
C1 <img src=\"available.png\"> <img src=\"available.png\"> <img src=\"available.png\"> <img src=\"available.png\">
```

For each entry

Hopefully this makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$json = json_decode($getJSON, true);
foreach($json as $key=>$val){
    echo $key." ".implode($val)."<br/>";
}
```

You can see it [here](https://3v4l.org/omqlj)

Note: if you want a space between the `<img>` tags, use `implode(' ', $val)`

Comment: That was it! Thanks much!